# Migrating from UIWebView to WKWebView/ Configuration cannot be nil

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, wkwebview

Error when trying to switch my objective-c project from UIwebview to WKwebview

```
 NSURL* webViewURL = webView.request.URL;
NSString* urlString = [webViewURL absoluteString];
if([urlString containsString:@"usertoken"]){
    DDURLParser* urlParser = [[DDURLParser alloc] initWithURLString:urlString];
    NSString* userToken = [urlParser valueForVariable:@"usertoken"];
    if(userToken && ![userToken isEqualToString:@""]){
        [self loginUserWithAccessToken:userToken];
```

Property 'request' not found on object of type 'WKWebView *' I get this error

Comment: `webView` is an IBOutlet? Or where has it been initialized? How did you go from `UIWebView` to `WKWebView`? If you did by changing the class of the IBOutlet, you're wrong. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/71644749/1801544

Answer (score 0):

```
        NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"yourHTMLfileName" ofType:@"html"]; //
        NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
        NSURLRequest * request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
```